# Receiving ParseException with String containing ISO 8601 Formatted Date using Java 1.6

Tags: java, date, iso

Keep getting a ParseException when I try to parse a ISO 8601 formatted String into a Java Date  type.

```
String myDateString = "2014-07-04T22:59:36Z";  
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", Locale.US);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
Date formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(myDateString);
```

Keeps returning a ParseException:

```
Unparseable date: "2014-07-04T22:59:36Z"
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `X` (unquoted) rather than `'Z'`.  And you need the `:ss` for seconds -- `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble parsing a certain Date format, I keep getting ParseException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090946/trouble-parsing-a-certain-date-format-i-keep-getting-parseexception)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the seconds in your date format:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

For Java 6 & 7, add the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project. For Java 8 and later, *java.time* is built-in.

```
Instant.parse( "2014-07-04T22:59:36Z" )
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar`.

While built into Java 8 and later, a back-port to Java 6 and Java 7 is available. (see below)

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So **no need to specify a formatting pattern**. The `Instant` class can directly parse your input string.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2014-07-04T22:59:36Z" );
```

To generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2014-07-04T22:59:36Z

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).