# Parsing ISO 8601 date format like 2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, iso8601

I am trying to parse a `String` using `SimpleDateFormat`.

This is my current code:

```
public String getCreatedDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddEHH:mm:ss.zzzz");
    try {
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z");
        return date.toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "Error parsing date";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just put a constant in the parse() method for testing purposes.

So, this is what I am trying to parse:

> 2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z

This is the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern that I am using:

> yyyy-MM-ddEHH:mm:ss.zzzz

I keep getting the ParseException.

I know that it is proably because of the .zzzz at the end but I have no idea what .363Z might stand for so I just used some random letters. Bad idea.

I'll appreciate your help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you throw away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with this pattern (note the X at the end and the 'T' in the middle):

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
```

From Java's [SimpleDateFormat's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone):

> ISO 8601 Time zone:
>
> ...
>
> For parsing, "Z" is parsed as the UTC time zone designator.

And, from the part where it describes the different characters:

> X - Time zone - ISO 8601 time zone

**EDIT**

If using Android, then "X" is not supported.

You can use this pattern (note Z is a literal now):

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

But then you'll get the date on your current timezone and would need to convert it to UTC if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It sadly doesn't work yet. I get *IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character X* with your pattern. Which is weird because X clearly is a pttern characters as seen from documentation.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? And is it the Java SE or Android?

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8.0_40 and this is Android.

Comment: Well, it seems the "X" is not supported on Android. I'll update my answer and include a part for Android as well.

Comment: You can set the timezone for parsing/formatting with simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) to make your intent clear and avoid conversion after parsing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)

Comment: @AlainO'Dea your comment solved even one more problem that I've had. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Whiz my pleasure.  I was hoping it might.  That one line was the solution to many confusing bugs for me.  I've seen it time and again.  There's a bug that this fixes in OneLogin's SAML library.  https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml/AuthRequest.java#L36-37.  I meant to do a Pull Request, but forgot since I switched to OpenSAML instead.

Comment: **Never put quote marks around the `Z`.** Doing so is an instruction to treat the letter an a mere literal. You would be discarding valuable information, as `Z` means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Answer (score 11):

## tl;dr

Skip the formatting pattern. Standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is used by default.

```
Instant.parse( "2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z" )
```

---

## ISO 8601

Your string format is formally defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Basically your Question is a duplicate of this one, [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date).

## Alternatives

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091090/642706) by [eugenioy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907630/eugenioy) is correct.

But you should know that the old java.util.Date/.Calendar/java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided.

#### Outmoded Classes

Those old classes are now outmoded, first by the third-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, and now by the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)) built into Java 8 and later (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project).

Both java.time and Joda-Time use the ISO 8601 standard as their defaults when parsing/generating string representations of date-time values. So the code is simple, no need for custom formatter objects. **No need for all that format twiddling that caused your Exception.**

#### Time Zone

Both java.time and Joda-Time have a zoned date-time class that understands its assigned time zone (unlike java.util.Date). If you do not assign one, the JVM’s current default time zone is assigned.

Beware that the JVM’s current default time zone can change *at any time*. It can change at deployment, defaulting to whatever the host OS setting is. And it can change at any moment during runtime when any code in any thread of any app within the JVM calls [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-). So better to explicitly assign a desired/expected time zone.

#### java.time

The `Z` on the end of your string is short for Zulu and means UTC. The `Instant` class can directly parse that format, to represent a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution in nanoseconds.

```
String input = "2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

Change the time zone from UTC to some desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneID zone = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtMontréal = instant.atZone( zone ) ;
```

If you really need a java.util.Date for interoperability, convert.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = Date.from( zdtMontréal.toInstant() ) ;
```

### [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes:

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.8.1.

```
String input = "2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z" ;
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.UTC ;  //  Or: DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, zone ) ;
```

If you really need a java.util.Date for interoperability, convert.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very informative.