# parse String to 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ' ISODate java

Tags: java, mongodb, date, simpledateformat, isodate

How to convert String to **ISODate** format using **SimpleDateFormat**, which means that i want to finally get Date in java.util.Date format.

My string will look like **2017-02-17T09:28:03.000Z**, i want to convert it to date formt. I can do this in Joda date format, but since i am using mongoDB, it does not accept joda format.

```
   String startDateString1 =  "2017-02-17T04:23:17.452Z";      
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
    Date  startDate = df.parse(startDateString1);
    String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
```

above code is not working.

Comment: What is your java version ?

Comment: Is your time zone always `Z`? If not, what other things could it be?

Comment: Java 8 `java.time` is great for ISO dates and times. It seems to me that `Instant.parse()` would eat your string without a problem. If your MongoDB driver doesn’t accept an `Instant`, converting to `Date` is easy.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Parsing ISO 8601 date format like 2015-06-27T13:16:37.363Z in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31090946/642706).

Comment: I am using java 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working since Z is a reserved character used to interpret RFC-822 time zones :

> RFC 822 time zone: For formatting, the RFC 822 4-digit time zone format is used:
>
> ```
>  RFC822TimeZone:
>          Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
>  TwoDigitHours:
>          Digit Digit
> ```

Since Java 7, you can use X to interpret ISO-8601 time zones https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html . The following works :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

However, on my computer,

```
System.out.println(newDateString);
```

results in the following output :

> 2017-02-17T05:23:17.452+01

Alternatively, if you are sure to have only UTC dates, you could escape the Z letter with simple quotes :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

And here is the displayed result :

> 2017-02-17T04:23:17.452Z

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Java 8 like below.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-02-17T09:28:03.000Z");
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: A new JDBC driver should accept an `Instant` without it having been converted to `Date` (don’t know if such a new driver exists for MongoDB, nor whether the asker has got one, though).

Comment: I have checked already. I don't think there is one for MongoDB.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You could use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2017-02-17T04:23:17.452Z")` which will return a Calendar object. You can call `getTime()` on it to get a Date object.