# Format date and time in String format from an API response

Tags: java, android, date, time, formatting

I'm using the Guardian API to get recent news stories about football.

I want to show date and time info to the user, but not in the format the API throws it back to me.

When requesting webPublicationDate after querying http://content.guardianapis.com/search?page-size=10&section=football&show-tags=contributor&api-key=test I get the response in this format:

> 2017-06-22T16:18:04Z

Now, I want the date and time info in this format: 
e.g. *Jun 21, 2017* and *16:18* or *4:18 pm*.

While I basically know to format a `Date` object properly into this format:

```
/**
 * Return the formatted date string (i.e. "Mar 3, 1984") from a Date object.
 */
private String formatDate(Date dateObject) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(dateObject);
}

/**
 * Return the formatted date string (i.e. "4:30 PM") from a Date object.
 */
private String formatTime(Date dateObject) {
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    return timeFormat.format(dateObject);
}
```

But I can't seem to convert the response I get into a `Date` object.

Comment: Also duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31090946

Answer (score 2):

You can format the text this way:

```
package com.mkyong.date;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDateExample5 {

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    String dateInString = "2014-10-05T15:23:01Z";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"));
        System.out.println(date);

        System.out.println("time zone : " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

> Z suffix means UTC, java.util.SimpleDateFormat doesn’t parse it correctly, you need to replace the suffix Z with ‘+0000’.

Code from here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly working with `SimpleDateFormat` (as this old API has [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)), you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To use it in **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The main classes to be used are `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime` (which can parse the date/time input) and `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` (to control the output format).

If you are reading this field (`2017-06-22T16:18:04Z`) as a `String`, you can create a `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-06-22T16:18:04Z");
```

If you already have a `java.util.Date` object, you can convert it using `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` with a `org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset`:

```
Date date = // get java.util.Date
ZonedDateTime z = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

In the end, the `ZonedDateTime` object will have the `webPublicationDate` value.

To get the different output formats, just create one `DateTimeFormatter` for each format. In the examples below, I also use `java.util.Locale` class to make sure the month names are in English:

```
// for Mar 3, 1984
DateTimeFormatter f1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
// for 4:40 PM
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
// for 16:18
DateTimeFormatter f3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(f1.format(z)); // Jun 22, 2017
System.out.println(f2.format(z)); // 4:18 PM
System.out.println(f3.format(z)); // 16:18
```

The output is:

> Jun 22, 2017
>   4:18 PM
>   16:18

Note that it uses the UTC timezone (the `Z` in `2017-06-22T16:18:04Z`). If you want to display the date and time in another timezone, just use the `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` class:

```
System.out.println(f3.format(z.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))); // 17:18
```

The output is `17:18` (becase London is in summer time now).

Note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). To find the timezone that better suits each region, use the `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` method and check which one fits best for your use cases.

---

If you don't want to add another dependency to your project and use `SimpleDateFormat`, you do something similar (create one parser and 3 output formatters, and use English locale). Also don't forget to set the timezone - I'm using UTC below, but you can change it to whatever timezone you want.

```
// parse date
String dateInString = "2017-06-22T16:18:04Z";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = parser.parse(dateInString);

// create output formatters (set timezone to UTC)
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
SimpleDateFormat s1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
s1.setTimeZone(utc);
SimpleDateFormat s2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
s2.setTimeZone(utc);
SimpleDateFormat s3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
s3.setTimeZone(utc);

System.out.println(s1.format(date));
System.out.println(s2.format(date));
System.out.println(s3.format(date));
```

The output will be the same:

> Jun 22, 2017
>   4:18 PM
>   16:18